# Database design software for a student?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I am taking a database class and have to draw a bunch of different kinds of diagrams.  Specifically, I need to draw ERD and dependency diagrams.  The instructor does not want any hand drawn diagrams but does not offer any clue as to what software to use.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I would start with pen-and-paper.

Comment: I'd go for pencil-and-paper... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have been cobbling together various shapes in Visio.  I don't like it but it seems to be the best way to create all the different diagrams in my text.

Answer (score 1):

[VisioModeler by Visio now exists as free, unsupported software](http://download.cnet.com/Visio-2000-Tool-VisioModeler-Unsupported-Product-Edition/3000-2064_4-10731607.html).  It's only good for physical ERD in my experience - it can't do logical models.

I've heard good things about [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DB Designer](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/).  It's free and has some useful features.  It is both Windows and Linux friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Dia. Kivio. Umbrello.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently discovered an editor called **RISE**, which is published by [Rise To Bloome](http://www.risetobloome.com/). It's simple and easy to use and it's free to download and keep. It currently only supports Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

ERWin currently has a free community edition. http://erwin.com/products/detail/ca_erwin_data_modeler_community_edition/

It's an excellent tool for getting your feet wet.